# Incorrect Album Artist and First Track in Plex

Tags: music, metadata, flac, music-management, plex

I ripped my parent’s Christmas CD collection as FLAC files with Windows Media Player. The first track of every album is just titled “Track 1” and the album artist of every album is “Various Artists”. They look fine in Windows Media Player, what went wrong?

If I go in and select “Fix Match” it will initially set the album artist’s name correctly before renaming them to “Unknown Artist”. The description and artist photo remain.

Server Version#:1.20.3.3483

Player Version#:1.21.0.1410-50a34597

Comment: How are the folders/files named? Have you followed the "Handling 'Various Artists' or Similar Compilations" section at https://support.plex.tv/articles/200265296-adding-music-media-from-folders/ ?

Comment: They're separated into folder by album, @Mokubai. They have the embedded tags like it talks about though.

Answer (score 1):

An incorrect title on the first track of a ripped CD is unfortunately a very common problem when ripping with Windows Media Player. Configuring WMP not to rip automatically when a new CD is inserted can help, but it's better to use a different program for ripping altogether. [Exact Audio Copy](https://www.exactaudiocopy.de/) is usually a good choice.

As for fixing the CDs that were already ripped, I suggest that you use the [Mp3tag](https://www.mp3tag.de/en/index.html) tag editor to take a look at the tags embedded in the FLAC files, and make corrections where needed.

Comment: I used https://picard.musicbrainz.org/ to fix most of them a bit more automatically. I'll give EAC a look, thanks!